# SOLVED React 18 - fetch before render - how to avoid re-render loop when using parameters?

Tags: reactjs

please consider my code, where I started to experiment with the usage of React 18's Suspense component. I found many examples, but all of them do not pass props to a child which is wrapped inside a Suspense component.

The moment I introduce a parameter (which is passed to the fetch API), I run into an endless re-render loop. Help me to understand, what I did wrong and how I could fix it.

Looking forward to your answers.

Here is the code causing the issue:

```
import './App.css';
import {Suspense} from "react"


const wrapPromise = (promise, todo_id) => {
  let status = "pending"
  let response;
  const suspender = promise(todo_id).then(
      (res) => {
          status = "success"
          response = res
      },
      (err) => {
          status = "error"
          response = err
      },
  )

  const read = () => {
    switch (status) {
        case "pending":
            throw suspender
        case "error":
            throw response
        default:
            return response
    }
  }

  return {read};
}

const fetchTodo = (todo_id) => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + todo_id)
  .then(response => response.json());

const wrappedFetchTodoRerenderLoop = (todo_id) => wrapPromise(fetchTodo, todo_id)

const MyTodo = (props) => {  
  console.log("redner")
  const todo = wrappedFetchTodoRerenderLoop(props.todo_id).read();

  return (
    <>
        <p>ID: {todo.id}</p>
        <p>Title: {todo.title}</p>
    </>
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading ...</p>} >
        <MyTodo todo_id={1}/>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Based on jsejcksn tip, I was able to fix my code from above:

```
import './App.css';
import {Suspense} from "react"

let cache = new Map();

// FIX - Caching is essential
const fetchData = (url) => {
  if (!cache.has(url)) {
    cache.set(url, fetch(url).then(r => r.json()));
  }
  return cache.get(url);
}

// FIX2 - I am not sure why this need to be so complicated, but it works
function use(promise) {
  if (promise.status === "fulfilled") {
    return promise.value;
  } else if (promise.status === "rejected") {
    throw promise.reason;
  } else if (promise.status === "pending") {
    throw promise;
  } else {
    promise.status = "pending";
    promise.then(
      (result) => {
        promise.status = "fulfilled";
        promise.value = result;
      },
      (reason) => {
        promise.status = "rejected";
        promise.reason = reason;
      }
    );
    throw promise;
  }
}

const MyTodo = (props) => {  
  console.log("redner")
  const todo = use(fetchData(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${props.todo_id}`))

  return (
    <>
        <p>ID: {todo.id}</p>
        <p>Title: {todo.title}</p>
    </>
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading ...</p>} >
        <MyTodo todo_id={1}/>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you examine the [example CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ymcj43?file=/ArtistPage.js) used in the [React documentation for `<Suspense>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)? It demonstrates and clarifies.